# How many queries are required to get the names and numbers of everyone in an Android contact group?

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, contactscontract

Using the Android 2.0 ContactsContract API, is it possible to build a list of objects representing contacts in a Contact Group like this:

```
public class GroupContact {  
    public String displayName;
    public List<String> phoneNumbers;
}
```

While making fewer than O(n) SQL queries?

Comment: Check out this ;)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422942/how-do-you-get-the-members-of-a-contact-group

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, it depends on a couple of things.

I presume by n you mean the number of phone numbers for the display name.

By queries I suspect you really mean cursor.moveToNext() calls.

In any case what you are looking for can be done with one query having n-1 moveTo*() calls.
The query makes use of the "view_data" view.

On the content provider side you want...

```
SELECT * FROM "view_data" WHERE "display_name" = 'mo howard';
```

or from the ContentResolver